# Spring Data, Hibernate, Transactions and rolling back on exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data

I have two repositories:

- locationRepository
- playerRepository

Consider the following situation:

```
@Transactional
public Player createPlayer(String locationName, String name) {
    Location location = new Location(locationName);
    location = locationRepository.save(location);

    Player player = new Player(name, location);
    return playerRepository.save(player);
}
```

There is constraint violation on player entity. I get: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

After that, I check the database:

- **player was not created**
- **location was created**

This method is annotated with @Transaction. So why the location is not rolled back? I was expecting that neither of this two were saved to DB on exception. How to rollback also the location?

EDIT:

```
@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(JpaVendorAdapter adapter) {
    ...

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(properties);

    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) 
{
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
JpaVendorAdapter createVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform(MySQL5Dialect.class.getName());

    return adapter;
}
```

EDIT:

Interesting thing is that the entry is persisted to database just after this call:

```
location = locationRepository.save(location);
```

I've set a breakpoint just after this call and checked the database. The entry was inserted immediately.

Comment: Do you have a transaction manager properly set up in your application context? What kind of class (service, controller ...) contains the `createPlayer` method? Do you use Java or XML based Spring configuration?

Comment: Is your connexion configured with autocommit=false?

Comment: I've updated the question with my configuration sample. The createPlayer is just regular class annotated with @Service. I'm not sure about where to set autocommit and should it be true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with MySQL. I didn't know that MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional should work in case of Spring based transaction management if your spring configuration is properly setup. If it is still not working then you can programmatically rollback a transaction in catch block by adding following line of code-

> TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

Also, what the import you are using for @Transactional, make sure it is -

> import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL5InnoDBDialect is needed in order for transactions to rollback the database.  This changed the engine from `engine=MyISAM` to `engine=InnoDB`. InnoDB Table Schemas support transactions.

I modified my spring boot 2.0 application.properties file and added the following:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```